# Laravel: Dynamic variable in config file (charlieuki receipt-printer)

Tags: laravel

I have a small web based project that uses thermal printer.
I have multiple users that uses diffrent printer name, and using the charlieuki receipt-printer for laravel.

this package has the /config/receiptprinter.php
My plan is to add 'user_printer' column in my users table, so admin can set a printer for each users.

`receiptprinter.php` as the (`'connector_descriptor' => 'PRINTER_NAME_HERE'`,)
and I need to dynamically change the `'PRINTER_NAME_HERE'` parameter which value comes from the database users table.

Are there any way to use value from database to change a value in config file of laravel?

Comment: maybe you can update your configs in controller for different users

Comment: You must be fetching name like `config('receiptprinter.connector_descriptor')`. Instead replace it with your dynamic varibale.